# Python Stopped Working While Training Data

Tags: python, keras, jupyter, training-data, jupyter-lab

I have a problem when I start training 
data. My python stopped working

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2, batch_size =2)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try running it again?

Comment: yes and changed the numbers

Comment: do uninstall python  ?